# Difference between 2 hardisks for HP ProLiant server

Tags: hard-drive, hp-proliant, mirroring

I have a HP ProLiant server: HP ProLiant DL360e Gen8 Entry

I have:

> 2 hardisk HP SAS 6 Gb/s 7.2 K 8.9cm HP 1TB HDD

Now I need to buy:

> HP SAS 6G    7.2K SFF 6.4cm SC 1TB HDD

to install also into the same server.. 
My question is.. I am woundering if the 6.4cm SC will fit into the server and If I can use both disk to create a Mirror.. 
I have a tight budget and given that the diffrence in price is close to 200 Dollars for the 2 new disk

Comment: Why are your guys so mean.. Or is it the Machine that is mean..  Why do you guys enjoy down grading ones question and blocking..? don't get you guys. Rome was not built in a day.. If you guys expect .. perfection.. then it okay with me.. but downgrading questions ..if it makes you guys a happy person so be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These disks are not compatible with each other. If your existing disks are 8.9cm (3.5"), then any new disks you buy should also be 8.9cm.

Comment: This is what the spec is saying..  Maximum Internal
>  Storage Hot Plug SFF SAS 9.6TB 8 x 1.2TB
>  Hot Plug SFF SATA 8.0TB 8 x 1TB
>  Hot Plug LFF SAS 16.0TB 4 x 4TB
>  Hot Plug LFF SATA 16.0TB 4 x 4TB
>  Hot Plug SFF SAS SSD 6.4TB 8 x 800GB
>  Hot Plug SFF SATA  SSD 6.4TB
>  8 x 800GB Hot Plug LFF SATA SSD 3.2TB 4 x 800GB

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the two first disk are 3.5' HDD, while the second two are 2.5' SFF HDD. So, the point is if your server supports 2.5' small form factor HDD.

Comment: So you are saying that if my Server support 2.5 then the mirrowing should work?

Comment: It's not a mirroring problem. You probably can not phisically fit a bare 2.5'' SFF disk in a 3.5'' slot. At least, you need an appropriate adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You need an adapter to mount a 2.5" drive in a 3.5" bay/caddy as well as the caddy itself.  Something like http://www.amazon.co.uk/General-Drive-HDD-Adapter-CADDY/dp/B00F3QFKNS

Other than that they use the same SAS interface so would be compatible.